# tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint does not save the best model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras callback to save the best weights and when I observe the training process (with verbose of the callback set to 1) it seems to correctly identify the best model according to the specified metric and save it with the correct epoch number and loss in the name of the weights file (you can specify that when constructing a callback object).

However, when I load the saved best weights, the model shows different performance. What may be the issue? The model is not using any stochastic features, and normal saving outside of training using model.save() and loading back retains the performance.

Comment: what do you mean by "shows different performance"

Comment: @GerryP it performs worse on the training data in terms of loss.

Comment: so you trained it and it ended up with say a certain validation loss, then saved it, reloaded it and trained it for more epochs and it was not as low a loss. What was your selection for the optimizer? I don't think optimizer state gets saved with checkpoint so that might be the cause. After a few epochs I would think it would start to perform better.